# Permission denied when trying to self-update composer

Tags: php, laravel, command, composer-php, iterm

When I am trying to self-update my composer, I get *"Permission Denied"* error.

Even when I use `sudo /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update`, it shows me `command not found`.

Please help me I have no idea about composer

Comment: try su instead of sudo

Comment: Try to call it with PHP directly. ```php composer.phar selfupdate```

Comment: it show an error message `su: Sorry`

Comment: @paskl It show me` Could not open input file: composer.phar` when trying `Could not open input file: composer.pharv`

Comment: Well, you have to give its full path if the .phar file is not in your current directory.

Comment: `pharv` you have an extra v.. from pasting?

Comment: currently i face `sudo: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar: command not found` problem
sry typing error just now

Comment: Add `-vvv` to the command to get full verbose debugging output. Without that it's just a guessing game.

Comment: `sudo -H composer self-update` fix my bug

Comment: This worked for me check if composer is in dir and check complete file name in this case I don't have .phar extension:
`sudo /usr/local/bin/composer self-update`

Answer (score 8):

Try following command:

```
sudo php /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
```

Make sure composer.phar file exist in "/usr/bin"

Comment: i'm having same error as above. and the composer.phar file does not exist in the usr/bin.

Comment: You can try this command even when composer self-update is giving error of Permission Denied.

Comment: Please note that (currently) running the selfupdate command with sudo, changes the owner of the cache directories inside your current users homedir.

In order to avoid derived permission problems, change back ownership of the cache directories:

    sudo chown -R <user>:<group> /home/<user>/.composer

Answer (score 6):

CentOS7

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/composer self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

### here are the [instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate) from the composer maintainers

On the official [Composer website (getcomposer.org)](https://getcomposer.org/) in the section headed "[self-update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate)", the maintainers give the following information:

> If you have installed Composer for your entire system (see global installation), you may have to run the command with root privileges
>
> `sudo -H composer self-update`
>
> If Composer was not installed as a PHAR, this command is not available. (This is sometimes the case when Composer was installed by an operating system package manager.)

### what's `sudo -H`?

from `man sudo`:

**-H, --set-home**

> Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to
> the home directory specified by the target user's password database
> entry. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.